# What interface-specific keyboard shortcuts are there?

Tags: pc, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've noticed when in the menu, there are a few undocumented keyboard shortcuts. I've found the following so far:

- <kbd>1</kbd> appears to work the same as <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>2</kbd> will compare items in the menu
- <kbd>3</kbd> will automatically junk something for you

I've noticed inconsistent behavior in dialogues - when speaking to a blacksmith trainer to see if these shortcuts worked at all in dialogues, I managed to spend my life's savings on training by hitting <kbd>1</kbd> in that context.

What other interface-specific keyboard shortcuts are there, and are they documented anywhere?

Comment: I know spacebar will often accept a dialog choice. Useful when you're combining a ton of shards into larger shards and don't want to mouse click.